# dbpedia spotlight dataset

Tags: java, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I  installed the DBpedia Spotlight from http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/download/release-0.5/dbpedia-spotlight-quickstart.zip and wanted to improve its dataset by downloading from https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Downloads.

Can someone tell me how to use the data from spotter lexicon and disambiguation index with the jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already downloaded and decompressed the files below:

```
wget http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/download/release-0.5/context-index-compact.tgz
tar zxvf context-index-compact.tgz
wget http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/download/release-0.4/surface_forms-Wikipedia-TitRedDis.uriThresh75.tsv.spotterDictionary.gz
gunzip surface_forms-Wikipedia-TitRedDis.uriThresh75.tsv.spotterDictionary.gz
```

Now you just need to change the server.properties file to point to your newly extracted files:

```
org.dbpedia.spotlight.index.dir = index-withSF-withTypes-compressed
org.dbpedia.spotlight.spot.dictionary = surface_forms-Wikipedia-TitRedDis.uriThresh75.tsv.spotterDictionary
```

If you are using the largest spotter dict, you may need to increase the java heap space -- e.g. -Xmx10G in your command line.

Comment: thanks very much Pablo. :)
I am interested in getting deeper and learning more about this project  
Dbpedia Spotlight. I referred to the documentation on official dbpedia site and was looking for technical implementation .