# dbpedia spotlight dataset

Tags: java, jar, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

In continuation of [dbpedia spotlight dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088289/dbpedia-spotlight-dataset), I followed the instructions for updating my dataset but got the following error:

```
INFO 2012-06-19 11:58:04,300 main [MergedOccurrencesContextSearcher] - Using index at: org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@/home/user_name/new/spotlight/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@671381e7
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user_name/new/spotlight/index/segments_bp (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:219)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.openInput(FSDirectory.java:345)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:265)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader$1.doBody(DirectoryReader.java:76)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:709)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:72)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:273)
    at org.dbpedia.spotlight.lucene.search.BaseSearcher.<init>(BaseSearcher.java:67)
    at org.dbpedia.spotlight.lucene.search.MergedOccurrencesContextSearcher.<init>(MergedOccurrencesContextSearcher.java:64)
    at org.dbpedia.spotlight.model.SpotlightFactory.<init>(SpotlightFactory.scala:71)
    at org.dbpedia.spotlight.web.rest.Server.main(Server.java:86)
```

I had been able to successfully use the spotter dictionary but couldn't use the index files.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to help you without sufficient information. The message complains that a file is not there. Is the file there? Is the directory there?

Please paste the result of the command

`ls -lah /home/user_name/new/spotlight/index`

Comment: sorry for the pain . I found the answer to my problem. There had been a problem in decompressing files individually which i was earlier using. Otherwise your directions helped me a lot.
BTW , I read the paper and saw configurable implementation of spotlight and was interested in configuring it for social media text. Can u help me how and where I should start from in editing and modifying codes to meet my purpose.

Comment: Social media text is short and often not very topically concentrated. This means you should use as much extra information as you can to help the algorithm. But, more importantly, we need to know what kinds of things you want to extract from that text: topics, people, locations, what? Best place to discuss this is on our [dbp-spotlight-users](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbp-spotlight-users) list.